# Google Chrome on mobile fires additional unwanted MouseEvent on file input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

I've run into some event related issues with Google Chrome (78) on mobile. I have a setup where a file input (including the label) is appended when clicking a button. The file input will replace the button entirely and will be appended in exactly the same spot as where the button originally was.

On most browsers, this works fine. However, it seems that the mobile version of Google Chrome will fire a delayed click event after the initial touch on the button, causing the click to activate the file upload dialog. This click is fired on the file input, even though the file input was not even present during the initial touch.

It's not possible to stop the propagation on the button click, since I am listening for a TouchEvent, but the additional event is a MouseEvent. I'd rather not listen to the MouseEvent just to stopPropagation to prevent any cross browser issues. PreventDefault is also not an option, since the button is located in a slider, which would break the slider functionality.

Another option is to hide the file input until an event loop has passed (setTimeout of 0), which essentially fixes the issue, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution. Do any of you have any potential fixes for the issues?

I've set up a CodePen with a minimal code example showcasing the issue: https://codepen.io/frankderouge/pen/wvvRPRV

The basic set up is that a file input is initially hidden and then shown when a button is clicked.

```
//This listener is added to the 'button'
document.querySelector('.toggle_off').addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {

  //This won't do anything since we're handling a touch event, not a click event. 
  e.stopPropagation();  

  //This fixes the dialog open but would break sliding functionality
  //e.preventDefault();

  //Hide the button
  e.target.style.display = 'none';

  //Then show the file input, on which the additional event will be triggered
  document.querySelector('.toggle_on').style.display = 'block';
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is known as a 'ghost click', which exists for compatibility reasons and is actually 'expected behavior'. I did not expect a ghost click to occur if the mouse event was not bound to the original element in the first place, but apparently this does happen in some browsers.

The ghost click can be prevented by calling preventDefaulton a TouchEvent, in the initial post I stated that:

> PreventDefault is also not an option, since the button is located in a
>   slider, which would break the slider functionality.

But I've recently learned that it does not matter on which 'part' of the touch the preventDefault is called on since the ghost click is always triggered after all the touch events. Therefore the issue with the scrolling being prevented does not occur if preventDefault is called on the touchend, rather than the touchstart or touchmove.

```
document.querySelector('.element').addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
  //Process the touch start event
});

document.querySelector('.element').addEventListener('touchend', (e) => {
  //Prevent default on the touchend, preventing the ghost click from happening
  //But still allowing the users to zoom and scroll
  e.preventDefault();
});
```